# Calculate sum entry by entry (and displaying each step) in a table that contains multiple different items

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

I have a process where multiple items in multiple iterations are being stored  into a storage. I am creating a entry for each item that is being moved to the storage, but now I have to make a self refreshing report which the workers can use to see in where they have stoped before they got distracted, went to a break, etc..

Here is a simplified example of what my table looks like:

```
╔═══════════╦══════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ Timestamp ║ Item ║ Loaded ║ Expected ║
╠═══════════╬══════╬════════╬══════════╣
║        10 ║ A1   ║      1 ║       14 ║
║         9 ║ A2   ║      1 ║        8 ║
║         8 ║ A1   ║     11 ║       14 ║
║         7 ║ A1   ║      1 ║       14 ║
║         6 ║ A1   ║      1 ║       14 ║
║         2 ║ A2   ║      6 ║        8 ║
╚═══════════╩══════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

In the report/sql procedure I wan to make it look like this:

```
╔═══════════╦══════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ Timestamp ║ Item ║ Loaded ║ Expected ║
╠═══════════╬══════╬════════╬══════════╣
║        10 ║ A1   ║      4 ║       14 ║
║         9 ║ A2   ║      7 ║        8 ║
║         8 ║ A1   ║     13 ║       14 ║
║         7 ║ A1   ║      2 ║        4 ║
║         6 ║ A1   ║      1 ║       14 ║
║         2 ║ A2   ║      6 ║        8 ║
╚═══════════╩══════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

The current value for each line entry (ordered by the timestamp, desending) is the predecessor items value plus the value that was moved in the current row.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of your result set I'm afraid. Could you elaborate further? Thanks.

Comment: Is there possibly a type-o in your expected results?

Comment: your example makes no sense but look at RunningValue() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this (by using the first apporach): https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals